# Touchpad gestures don't work on Dell XPS 15 L521x

Tags: unity, 12.10, touchpad, multi-touch

I'm trying to get multi-touch gestures working on my Dell XPS 15. Two finger scrolling works but three or four finger gestures do not. I know that the touchpad is capable of multi-touch gestures because it works fine in Windows. I've tried several things already:

- Installing touchegg from the repository
- Installing touchegg from source
- Installing Sputnik kernel and policykit updates from Sputnik PPAs

The first fails with a segmentation fault when run, the second gives errors during compile about missing files, and the third installed fine but nothing changed. Compilation errors can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/X8RtAJzQ).

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2051324
That's pretty much the closest you can get to a "god" experience with the XPS L521X's touchpad!!!

Comment: Of course Windows can't either. The driver that comes with your laptop can do that. Try using Windows without the driver. And since linux is sometimes out of luck in case of drivers, specially for touchpad, I'd say don't put much hope in it. Just my opinion.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel: I'm using it now and it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Nimble, have you looked at this wiki page? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

Comment: Also, this page gives more information on touchegg and how to set it up, but I don't think it has been updated since 2011. https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/

Comment: It looks like touchegg takes some extra work to get things working on Unity but works "out of the box" in GNOME. http://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

Install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch and xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-multitouch
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synpatics
```

It has solved touchpad issues on other brand name laptops, don't know about Dell.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 14.04 all working fine for me , i suggest you to upgrade to ubuntu  14.04 or try find out whats ubuntu 14.04 using that causing the difference . .

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu Unity, 3- and 4-touch gestures are reserved to the window manager (Unity), and the 3-finger window management gestures are disabled for touchpads.  I'm no longer clear on the rationale behind disabling them for touchpads, it was done in early in 2013.