# how to achieve multi touch gestures in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, multi-touch

is it possible to get multitouch gestures in ubuntu 14.04 like macbook?
if possible how to activate or install multi touch gestures ?
my laptop is lenovo z580.it has syanptics touchpad which supports multi touch of 4 fingers as of my knowledge. 
i tried touchegg but no use.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

Installation

- install touchegg: `sudo apt-get install touchegg`
- install [Touchegg-GCE](https://github.com/Raffarti/Touchegg-gce): You have to `git clone` (or download) Touchegg-GCE from github and then manually compile it, it needs qt4 so `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools` then open a terminal into the Touchegg-GCE directory and type `/usr/bin/qmake-qt4` and `make`. Now launch touchegg-gce and configure your gestures.

  Autostart and configuration: into `~/.config/autostart/`
- create an executable (`chmod +x touch.sh`) script touch.sh with the following code. It is necessary to disable the default behaviour of the trackpad for 2-3 fingers gestures

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  synclient TapButton2=0
  synclient TapButton3=0
  synclient ClickFinger2=0
  synclient ClickFinger3=0
  synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
  synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
  ```
- create two launchers: one for the script(1) and the other for touchegg(2).

  (1) touch.desktop

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Exec=/home/<user>/.config/autostart/touch.sh
  Hidden=false
  NoDisplay=false
  X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
  Name[it_IT]=TouchScript
  Name=TouchScript
  Comment[it_IT]=Enable Touchegg 2-3 fingers
  Comment=Enable Touchegg 2-3 fingers
  ```

  (2) touchegg.desktop

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Touchegg
  GenericName=Touchégg
  Comment=Touchégg Gestures Manager
  Exec=/usr/bin/touchegg %u
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Name[it_IT]=touchegg.desktop
  ```

Comment: Does this work in Unity? Or it must be Gnome like the next answer?

Comment: I don't see this directory after I run the install command: /usr/bin/qmake-qt4  What do? I'm using Unity, not Gnome

Answer (score 4):

I have not been able to get multitouch gestures support with touchegg on Unity. However, after installing Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, touchegg works like a charm.

Comment: where you be able to get four finger touch like macbook ?? and could you please explain the steps to install and configure touchegg for multitouch??

Comment: I have corrected my answer above. I had forgot the "not". With touchegg on Ubuntu Gnome, I have been able to get four fingers touch. You can install it from ubuntu repo.

Comment: I guess you meant "I have been unable" or "I haven't been able". Double negatives in english are interpreted like in formal logic, and your first sentence implies you have achieved multitouch gestures on Unity ;)

Comment: Damn! You are right! Fixed.

Comment: @Jean-Louis, could you explain **how** you got it to work? It would be much appreciated :)

Comment: More or less the same as described in the answer of [user2429461](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04/451943#answer-463003). The key for me was it *didn't* work with default Ubuntu flavour with Unity. Instead I had to re-install Ubuntu Gnome to make touchégg work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 14.04 and using a logitech mini-keyboard with touchpad I have gestures enabled by default, I didn't installed anything specific.
Using two fingers I can zoom in/out or scroll pages.

Edit: I tried also on an other system in a HP laptop, so I really believe that basic gestures are now active by default in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Pilot6: thank you, but in this case the "new question" was very secondary, the main motivation to reply to the question in the thread  was to bring my experience that basic multitouch in ubuntu 14.04 is enabled by default..

Comment: @Antonello: that's not very clear from your description.  Please [edit] your answer, provide some screen shots on how to enable it, ...  Otherwise your answer will be deleted automatically by the system because of low quality soon...

Answer (score 0):

You should try [xSwipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe)! Works very effective