# How can I configure Touchegg on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mouse, touchegg

how can I configure touchegg on ubuntu 14.04 and use the gestures instead of unity gestures
I have Dell xps L502x and synaptics trackpad

Comment: I achieve my score with this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04

Hope this is helpful,
Matteo

Answer (score 7):

I have found a much easier solution: just create a file ".xprofile" in your home folder with the following content:

```
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0

touchegg &
```

The first two lines are only needed if you want to use gestures with three fingers. If you leave them out, touchegg will only recongnize gestures with 4 or more fingers.

Alternatively, run the following command that does the same:

```
echo "synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient TapButton3=0

touchegg &" > ~/.xprofile
```

Tochegg will also start on every boot. This worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and should work on any other Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override Unity's 3 and 4 fingers gestures just like that. From [Touchégg's FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/FAQ)

> Unity reserves to itself gestures with 3 and 4 gestures making impossible to Touchégg make use of it.

[In this post](http://ineed.coffee/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/), the author explains how to disable the buid-in gestures modifying Unity's sourcecode. Is written for Ubuntu 12.10 but some comments say that it works on 14.04 too. The relevant part for your question is (copy-pasted)

> We obtain Unity sourcecode with the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get build-dep unity
> cd /tmp
> mkdir unity
> cd unity
> apt-get source unity
> ```
>
> To disable its built-in multitouch gestures, we open the file
>   `/tmp/unity/unity-*/plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp` with a text
>   editor (e.g., gedit or Sublime Text 2).
>
> After we locate the method `UnityScreen::InitGesturesSupport()` (line
>   3381 for Unity 6.10.0, line 3287 for Unity 7.0.0), we comment all the
>   lines starting with gestures_.
>
> This is how it will look like:
>
> ```
> void UnityScreen::InitGesturesSupport()
> {
>   std::unique_ptr<nux::GestureBroker> gesture_broker(new UnityGestureBroker);
>   wt->GetWindowCompositor().SetGestureBroker(std::move(gesture_broker));
>   /*
>   gestures_sub_launcher_.reset(new nux::GesturesSubscription);
>   gestures_sub_launcher_->SetGestureClasses(nux::DRAG_GESTURE);
>   gestures_sub_launcher_->SetNumTouches(4);
>   gestures_sub_launcher_->SetWindowId(GDK_ROOT_WINDOW());
>   gestures_sub_launcher_->Activate();
>
>   gestures_sub_dash_.reset(new nux::GesturesSubscription);
>   gestures_sub_dash_->SetGestureClasses(nux::TAP_GESTURE);
>   gestures_sub_dash_->SetNumTouches(4);
>   gestures_sub_dash_->SetWindowId(GDK_ROOT_WINDOW());
>   gestures_sub_dash_->Activate();
>
>   gestures_sub_windows_.reset(new nux::GesturesSubscription);
>   gestures_sub_windows_->SetGestureClasses(nux::TOUCH_GESTURE
>                                          | nux::DRAG_GESTURE
>                                          | nux::PINCH_GESTURE);
>   gestures_sub_windows_->SetNumTouches(3);
>   gestures_sub_windows_->SetWindowId(GDK_ROOT_WINDOW());
>   gestures_sub_windows_->Activate();
>   */
> }
> ```
>
> We re-build Unity .deb packages and install them in our system.
>
> ```
> cd /tmp/unity/unity-*
> dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
> cd ..
> sudo dpkg -i *deb
> sudo apt-get -f install
> sudo apt-get autoremove
> ```
>
> Optionally, we may want to block upgrades to Unity packages. In this
>   way, we do not have to repeat the patch steps every time an upgrade is
>   released. However, we might miss important bug fixes.
>
> What follows blocks updates to Unity:
>
> ```
> echo "unity hold"|sudo dpkg --set-selections
> ```
>
> After a logout and a login, we can see that (among the others) Unity
>   3-fingers drag gestures has disappeared.

Another solution would be to get a different desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and did not need to make any changes on Unity. I remember last versions of Ubuntu it was a necessary step.

Below a video I did long time ago; however, as I said, I use Ubuntu 14.04 and just installed *touchegg* following this link (but not doing the Unity change part):

[OS X-like multitouch gestures for Macbook Pro running Ubuntu](http://ineed.coffee/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/)

And my home made video showing that it works fine (even five fingers it is possible). The *touchegg* config file is in the video description.

[Ubuntu 12.10 Multi Gestures (Pt) - Tutorial Link in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mvN9sSCeOs&feature=gp-n-y&google_comment_id=z12bft2rvsasyrf4a04cgzdqypjojv3jqc4)

Hope it works.

Comment: One more thing: install touchegg from the website. 
If does not work, install via apt-get. 
You wont have any issue with unity,

Comment: For ubuntu 16.04 I didn't need to modify Unity either. I've added installed from ubuntu repos 'touchegg' and added to the .xprofile the 'touchegg &' command