# How do I enable touch gestures in Ubuntu 14.04 lts (Unity) WITHOUT a Synaptics touchpad?

Tags: 14.04, unity, touchpad, multi-touch

I'm currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity on a relatively new ASUS Zenbook UX303-LB. I have been trying unsuccessfully to get gestures working for a good several weeks now, on and off, as I currently have NO gesture support. All I can do is tap 1 finger to click, drag 1 finger around to move the cursor, and use the physical buttons. I don't even have any of the gestures [listed here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/TouchpadSupport) that should *supposedly* work on any touchpad right out of the box (tested multiple times and confirmed).

**I tried following the steps in the answers to [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04), to no avail.**

I also tried doing something similar to the first answer in [this other (also similar) question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544821/how-can-i-configure-touchegg-on-ubuntu-14-04) - didn't help, but it did give me a message on boot telling me I don't have Synaptics drivers installed, which is what led me to discover **I have a FocalTech touchpad, not Synaptics.** I did NOT rebuild Unity from source, because that only (potentially) changes 3-4 touch gesture behavior, which I don't really care about.

I then proceeded to *try* and follow some of the steps from the [Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/TouchpadSupport) I linked above, but they seem to be written only for Synaptics touchpads (and are 3+ years old).

In any case, this is what I get out of xinput list-props [my touchpad]:

```
Device 'PS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad in mouse emulation mode':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (264): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (267):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (256):    2, 1
    Device Node (257):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (268): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (270):  0
    Axis Labels (271):  "Rel X" (149), "Rel Y" (150)
    Button Labels (272):    "Button Left" (142), "Button Unknown" (259), "Button Right" (144), "Button Wheel Up" (145), "Button Wheel Down" (146)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (273): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0
```

This thing works like an absolute charm in Windows 10, so I know there isn't anything wrong with it. Anyone know what to do?