# How to enable multi-touch gestured with Apple Magic Trackpad on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: touchpad, bluetooth, multi-touch, apple

I've successfully paired my Apple Magic Trackpad (first revision) by Bluetooth. The cursor movement, single/double-click and two-finger scroll - works great.
But I'd like to enable other gestures, like zooming, change desktop-workspaces with a swipe, etc.
I googled the problem and found two packets that could help me: touchegg and mtrack, but neither did help on my Ubuntu 16.04.
Does anyone have experience with configuring Apple Magic Trackpad?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to swipe with the Magic Trackpad or similar good touchpad, is to use and configure libinput-gesture (https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) to convert gestures to xdotool compiz windows arrangements.
Touchegg is good for a touchscreen. Both work well together on a laptop with both input touch devices.

My Full example here :
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/touch-input-with-touchpad-libinput-and-touchscreen-synaptics/12931

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question a while ago and as @xlinbsd said, Touchegg seems to be the most highly recommended package to use to configure multitouch gestures for Magic Trackpad.

Now that you know about Touchegg, there are a ton of resources available explaining how to use it with the Magic Trackpad, e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544821/how-can-i-configure-touchegg-on-ubuntu-14-04), [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/add-multitouch-gestures-ubuntu/), [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-macbook-touchpad-gestures-on-linux/) (if you just search *touchegg magic trackpad* in this forum you'll get tons of results)

If touchegg doesn't work for you I've seen other packages recommended, like [libinputgestures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789915/ubuntu-16-04-multitouch-gestures)

Good luck! Let us know how it works out!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/820372)

Comment: @SorenA This appears to be an attempt to answer the question to me.