# touch pad gesture to switch workspace

Tags: dell, touchpad, workspaces, gestures

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I would like to know how can I Achieve three four finger gestures to switch workspace and zoom in zoom out , things like these.
It would be great help, if any of the member can post the complete procedure to do so .I googled and found few blogs explaining this but those were old and may not work on trusty.

thanks

Comment: I tried solution on this post [link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04) . but could not get it worked may be touchegg is not recognizing the gestures

Comment: update: touchegg is not recognizing gestures with more than two fingers.evry gesture that i make with more than two finger it is taking it as two finger.Any help on how can get it recognize more than two?

Comment: Finally got it worked not with the help of touchegg but with using xswipe.Posting it as answer. hope it helps other!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

In newer systems ( Ubuntu 13.10 and up, Arch, etc.) the version of the xorg input driver shipped no longer supports utilizing gestures using the synclient driver. However, there is a workaround to make this workable. Follow the steps below to install a forked version of the xorg input driver.
Install a Working xserver-xorg-input-synaptics Driver

### Ubuntu 13.10, Mint 16, and Up

First download the following dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libevdev-dev autoconf automake libmtdev-dev xorg-dev xutils-dev libtool
```

Now, we need to remove the old driver so the new one will overwrite it

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Then, clone the source and build the new driver!

```
git clone https://github.com/felipejfc/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.git

cd xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/

./autogen.sh

./configure --exec_prefix=/usr

make

sudo make install
```

When this completes, reboot and make sure your pointer works.
Arch Linux

Installation on Arch is much easier. Simply grab the package from the AUR and reboot!
yaourt xf86-input-synaptics-xswipe-git
sudo reboot

Make sure your pointer works as expected after a reboot
Setting up xSwipe

First install the dependencies.
     sudo apt-get install libx11-guitest-perl

Then enable SHMConfig to allow for handling of the gestures.
     mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/

```
 sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

Fill the file with the following and save it!

> Section "InputClass"
>
> Identifier "evdev touchpad catchall"
>
> Driver "synaptics"
>
> MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
>
> MatchIsTouchpad "on"
>
> Option "Protocol" "event"
>
> Option "SHMConfig" "on"
>
> EndSection

Now clone xSwipe to a location of your choose.

```
 git clone https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe.git
```

And change the eventkey.cfg file to your favourite Gesture. 
Ignore the ubuntu and gnome sections for unity and cinnnamon.and add your gestures in 'other' part of file.

```
 cd xSwipe/
 nano eventkey.cfg
```

Now test by running:

```
 perl xSwipe.pl
```

Try to swipe with different gestrues and If they are, you may now add the script to your start up programs depending on your environment. After it is added, reboot and you should have working multitouch gestures!
Enable Natural Scrolling (Optional)

The last step to take is to fix scrolling broken by the SHMConfig. I prefer natural (reverse) scrolling so this is necessary. This step is not necessary if you prefer traditional scrolling. First, create a file called .Xmodmap in your home directory
       cd ~
      nano .Xmodmap

Fill the file with the following to enable natural scrolling. (Note: In mint, this doesnt work in system apps for some odd reason, but in Arch it works fine)
pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12

Save the file and restart your session. Your trackpad is now all set up!

Update: This seems to take about an hour out of my battery life. To get around this, I change the sensitivity with the parameter -m 30.

Credits:http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install any extra driver software for Dell laptops.

You can simply double tap with three fingers in Dell touchpad to switch to the previous workspace.

For zoom-in and zoom-out you can use scrolling using two fingers as it happens for most of the image viewers.

Dell inspiron 3542 and Ubuntu 14.04