# Multitouch gestures do not work on an Asus X555LA

Tags: touchpad, asus, multi-touch

Just bought an Asus X555LA laptop, and multitouch on the touchpad does not seem to work. I'm running Ubuntu 14.10, Gnome edition. Is there any solution or special driver for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `touchegg` to get the multi-touch gestures working.

`sudo apt-get install touchegg`

For steps to configure it, you can refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04/463003#463003).

Comment: This is not work for me on the same notebook model
`synclient` show the error
`Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`
but `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed