# ubuntu 14.04 could not use two-finger scroll[Razer blade]

Tags: 14.04

I’ve just installed ubuntu 14.04 on my new Razer blade, but I just can't use the srolling with the touchpad, and there is no other options on the Mouse&Touchpad setting interface, I wanna use two-finger scrolling on it, just like it was on my old Thikpad. So what should I do to fix it? Anyone could help me? Thank you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer kerenls have the fix already.  If it isn't an issue you can install a newer kerenl.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.0-vivid/

Download the generic amd64.deb files and the all.deb file.

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

in the directory where they are downloaded. Then edit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules and add hid_rmi to the end of the file. Finally run update-initramfs. Something like

```
sudo echo "hid_rmi" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now restart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all touchpads support that feature.  I have an HP like that, and when I'm out in the field I just have to edge scroll, and I hate it.  When I get home I plug in my Logitech K400r wireless keyboard and TWO-FINGER trackpad in one, and an external monitor, and suddenly I get two finger scrolling.

When my Logitech keyboard is plugged in, the 2 finger scrolling is not greyed out.
When I'm using the HP without the Logitech, the 2 finger scrolling is greyed out.

Until this happened to me, I never realized that not all trackpads are alike.  Now that I know the difference, I would never buy another laptop again without checking first.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to use it with a mouse everywhere... OMG, I wish it will be supported later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Install touchegg, it works fine for me now. Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: I've followed your advice and tried as the link, however, it's a pity that it didn't work on my laptop, I've googled this problem and it seems this bug have been fixed in the 3.17 kernel, I'll try it later. BTW, Thank you all the same.