# OS X - like trackpad gestures with TouchEgg - rebuilding unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, touchpad, multi-touch, touchegg

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with unity, and I know that Touchegg is not compatible with unity. But according to [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451386/how-to-achieve-multi-touch-gestures-in-ubuntu-14-04), some people say that worked for them with unity.

I am trying these instructions to disable unity's default trackpad gestures, and I guess that after some updates, some file types of the unity building packages have been changed.

When I do:

```
cd /tmp/unity/unity-*
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i *deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I see there aren't any `*deb` files in the containing file.

My question is how to rebuild these edited unity.

These are the files under the file "Unity":

```
unity-7.2.6+14.04.20151021
unity_7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1.diff.gz
unity_7.2.6+14.04.20151021-0ubuntu1.dsc
unity_7.2.6+14.04.20151021.orig.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the TouchEgg seems like the only option, there is another trackpad application named ["xSwipe"](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe). It's compatible with both unity and gnome and it works like a charm. No need to dealing with unity rebuilding!

Answer (score 1):

There is also Ginn, which according to the [ubuntu wiki is compatible with unity](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/Ginn).

This article from August 2014 [compares the three options: Ginn, xSwipe, and TouchEgg](https://www.elementarynow.com/multitouch-trackpads-luna/). Things might have changed since then. I haven't had the chance to test any of them yet.