# Can I Use Wayland as daily driver in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, wayland

I just Switched from Pop OS 19.10 to Ubuntu 20.04.
I am really liking ubuntu as it gives me smoother experience on my laptop ASUS X505za with ryzen 5 2500u.
I just tried wayland and its giving me better performance than xorg Why?
Should i Use it.

Comment: I have been using Wayland as a daily driver since 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryzen 5 2500U CPU has Radeon Vega 8 integrated graphics which works out the box with Wayland, so there's no need to switch to Xorg because the ASUS X505ZA doesn't have a discrete graphics card which could give better performance by installing a proprietary graphics driver. If Wayland gives better performance on your laptop there's no reason not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation.I am using it but the only issue i face is that touchpad gestures cant be configured.do you know any way of doing it in wayland.

Comment: Install touchegg multitouch gesture recognizer in 20.04 with `sudo apt install touchegg` and configure it in GNOME desktop environment or for alternative steps to configure it refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/463003).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Wayland works generally well. The only issue I encountered is if you need to use screen sharing in some applications (for example Skype). I had to switch back to Xorg because I'm using Skype and occasionally with screen sharing, in this time of lockdown.

Test your setup and the applications you use and decide for yourself what works best for you.